# Format the partial dependence plot

Tags: python

I tried to plot a partial dependence plot chart for the gbm model. The code is below.

```
gbm_partialplot, axs= plot_partial_dependence(gbm_reg, features = [0,6,8, 5], X = inde2,
                                          feature_names= feature_names2, 
                                          grid_resolution=50, n_cols = 2)
gbm_partialplot.suptitle('Partial dependence')
gbm_partialplot.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

The produced chart was shown below. There are three issues. First, I want to remove the label of y-axis. Through some search, I found the code `gbm_partialplot.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)`, but it threw me a error "`'list' object has no attribute 'get_yaxis'`". Secondly, the x-axis of the top two charts disappear after I set `ncol` to `2`. Thirdly, the title seems to be too far away from the chart.I wonder how should I change the codes. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you need a number here: `.axes[n].get_yaxis()` with n between 0 and 3.